# Drools Unterminated Collection Element Error

Tags: java, drools

I have when statement that goes from an if statement to the else statement:

```
rule "rule"
 ruleflow-group "ruleFlow"
    when
    $block : Block()
    $inst : BlockInstitution(blockInstitutionCategory!=null) from $block.getInstitution()
    $categorycode : InstitutionCategory(Constants.INSTITUTION_CATEGORY_CODE.equals(institutionCategoryCode)) from $inst.getInstitutionCategory()
    $list : BlockInstitution(Constants.validNonList not contains dealCode) from $block.getInstitution()
    then
    Service $service = new Service();
     try {
          JsonObject enquiry =
              $service.execute($block.getTransaction().getNumber()).get();
          if (enquiry.isEmpty()) {
            $block.getBusinessValidationResult().add(ValidationResult.NOT_FOUND);
            $block.getMsg().setStatusText(Constants.NOT_FOUND);
     } 
     else {
            String numberFromService = statusEnquiry.getString(Constants.NUMBER);
            String cardExpiryFromService =
                enquiry.getString(Constants.EXPIRY_DATE);
            String paymentRequestorIdentifier =
                enquiry.getString(Constants.IDENTIFIER);
            String paymentExpiryDate = enquiry.getString(Constants.EXPIRY_DATE);
            String statusText = enquiry.getString(Constants.STATUS_TEXT);
            String providerIdentifier =
                enquiry.getString(Constants.PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER);
             if (Objects.nonNull(paymentExpiryDate)) {
                  paymentExpiryDate =
                      EncryptionUtilFactory.getInstance().decryptData(paymentExpiryDate);
                  if (paymentExpiryDate.length() == 4) {
                    paymentExpiryDate =
                        paymentExpiryDate.substring(2, 4) + paymentExpiryDate.substring(0, 2);
                  }
                  paymentExpiryDate =
                      EncryptionUtilFactory.getInstance().encryptData(paymentExpiryDate);
                }
              if (Objects.nonNull(cardExpiryFromService)) {
               cardExpiryFromService =
                   EncryptionUtilFactory.getInstance().decryptData(cardExpiryFromService);
               if (cardExpiryFromService.length() == 4) {
                 cardExpiryFromService =
                     cardExpiryFromService.substring(2, 4) + cardExpiryFromService.substring(0, 2);
               }
               cardExpiryFromService =
                   EncryptionUtilFactory.getInstance().encryptData(cardExpiryFromService);
             }
            
            
            $block.getTransaction().setServiceNumber(numberFromService);
            $block.getTransaction().setServiceAccountExpirationDate(cardExpiryFromService);
            $block.getTransaction().setPaymentExpiryDate(paymentExpiryDate);
            $block
                .getTransaction()
                .setFlag(Constants.ID_SET.contains(providerIdentifier));

            
            $block.getTransaction().setProviderIdentifier(providerIdentifier);
            String text = $block.getTransaction().getPrimaryAccountNumber();
            $block.getTransaction().setText(text);
            $block.getTransaction().setStatusText(statusText);
            $block
                .getTransaction()
                .setPaymentRequestorIdentifier(paymentRequestorIdentifier);

            if (!Constants.STATUS.equals(statusText)) {
              switch (statusText) {
                case Constants.INACTIVE_STATUS:
                  $block.getBusinessValidationResult().add(ValidationResult.INACTIVE);
                  break;
                case Constants.CANCELLED_STATUS:
                  $block.getBusinessValidationResult().add(ValidationResult.CANCELLED);
                  break;
                case Constants.SUSPENDED_STATUS:
                  $block.getBusinessValidationResult().add(ValidationResult.SUSPENDED);
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          $block.getBusinessValidationResult().add(ValidationResult.CALL_FAILED);
          $block.getTransaction().setStatusText(Constants.NOT_FOUND);
        }

end
```

ERROR:

```
[Error: unterminated collection element]
[Near : {... _FOUND);          } else {            String numberFr ....}]
```

As the code goes from the if block to the else block it gives me an error: "Unterminated Collection Element".

Is there anything you see that indicates what's wrong.  I can't find anything on the Internet that discusses this error.  I've found "Unterminated String Element", but nothing on collection elements.

Comment: That rule is horrifying. And I say that in the nicest way possible. My guess is that the overly-complex right hand side ("then" clause) is causing the compiler to choke. Have you considered refactoring that code into, well, code? (Eg moving it into Java and then calling it from the rule)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas We're moving it from Java into a rule b/c it was causing problems with a new feature we're implementing.  We're considering just leaving it as Java and adding a new Kie Session after the Java code though, so that we can write our new rules but maintain the current infrastructure.

Comment: I meant moving the stuff in the right hand side into java code and invoking it from the rule. You can still have your rule, but let the real compiler do the compiling and optimization and just call that method from the rule. (Which would also allow you to properly unit test it.)

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. Thanks for the suggestion.